# Select a row where field name is enable and value is true

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am new to php, in my sql table I have a row with these columns:

```
id, custid, name, value
```

id is auto increment, custid is unique value, name is a enable (status parameter) and value set to true or false.

Now I just want to select a case where

```
 $sql = 'cu_id FROM table WHERE name = 'enable' AND value = 'true'' ;
```

in a PHP file, but my php file says, line has syntax error, at enable.

Can anyone please have a look what is it :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass your query with in the double coats, it is the best practice

```
$sql = "cu_id FROM table WHERE name = 'enable' AND value = 'true'" ;
```

Comment: Not sure true should be quoted. Tinyint 1 / 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes,

```
$sql = "cu_id FROM table WHERE name = 'enable' AND value = 'true'";
```

but the best way to do is to use prepared statement to avoid from sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You have following errors in your query:

1. You are using single quotes within single quotes.  You can fix this by wrapping double quoting the query string and keeping single quotes for column values. Or you can choose to escape the single quotes used in the values with a backslash, e.g. `\'enable\'`
2. Your table name is one of MySQL reserved words i.e. `table`.  When you use one of [MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) you need to quote them with backticks e.g `` `table ```.

Please try the following:

```
$sql = "cu_id FROM `table` WHERE name = 'enable' AND value = 'true'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes and instead of using true and false you can use 1 and 0. With default value 0 or 1 as you wish so that query will look like. You can also replace `value` as `status`

```
$sql = "select cu_id FROM table WHERE name = 'enable' AND status = 0";
```